# facelets insert/define with value binding expression

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, icefaces

I try to bind bean property to **ui:insert** name attribute.

```
<ice:panelTabSet var="tab" items="#{mainTabsTempl.tabs}">               
    <ice:panelTab label="#{tab.label}">  
        <ui:insert name="#{tab.tabContentUIName}">   
           content of #{tab.tabContentUIName} tab   
        </ui:insert>    
    </ice:panelTab>  
</ice:panelTabSet>
```

and **ui:insert** see this value binding expression like a string.

Is there any way to pass value binding expression?

Comment: I think you are trying to use wrong tool for the job. Please describe what you are trying to achieve without referring to insert/define.

Comment: I have edit my question. as you see i use `ui:insert` inside `c:forEach`, so I need to pass "name" attribute as variable.

Comment: How are you going to use this template? Mind posting part with ui:defines as you imagine it?

Comment: mrembisz, you absolutely rigth. I asked the question not correct. I cann't create template with dynamic composit element in this case. I only tried to build tabSet in loop and manage ui:insert names in java class and I didn't know how to pass binding expression in this case. My apologize.

Comment: Aren't you confusing [JSTL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) with [EL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)? You had `[jstl]` tag on the question which made totally no sense, so I just removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I see what you are trying to achieve. Unfortunately it is impossible for at least two reasons. First `ui:insert` supports literals only. It explicitly checks `name` attribute and throws an exception when it is not a literal. The second reason is `panelTabSet` is a component, so its variable - "tab" in your case - is available at rendering phase while `ui:insert`/`ui:define` are tag handlers executed during view construction.

You can try to rephrase your question and ask again. My understanding is you want to have an enriched tabset template/component to which you can pass a series of facets to be used as separate tabs. My guess would be trying composite components and `insertFacet` with `f:facet`. I haven't used composite components though so I won't be able to help here.

Comment: yes, that is what I meant. But main question was to use bean propertie value in `ui:insert` component attribute. Thank you for answer.